# Circuitikz: Anchor names of bipole terminals

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, coordinates, anchor

I want to use the left and right terminal of a bipole as an anchor to continue drawing from there. Resistors offer the anchors `left` and `right` and they are almost what I need. However, they are too tight to the bipole's body:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        % the bipole to whose anchors I want to connect to
        \draw (0,0)              to[R,name=somebipole,l=somebipole] ++(4,0);
        % attempt to use 'right' anchor
        \draw (somebipole.right) to[R,name=Rwrong,l=Rwrong]         ++(0,4);
        % attempt to hard-code coordinate (4,0)
        \draw (4,0)              to[R,name=Rcorrect,a=Rcorrect]     ++(0,4);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: attempt to use somebipole's right anchor]

I know that I could use `coordinate(sometemporarycoordinate)`, but what is the name of the outer anchors of a bipole, in this case 'somebipole'?

Comment: Welcome! Are you sure that this is an anchor? I was always under the impression that you should just use one path, `\draw (0,0)              to[R,name=somebipole,l=somebipole] ++(4,0)
   to[R,name=Rcorrect,a=Rcorrect]     ++(0,4);`, also because of the line joins. Of course, you can give the coordinate at the corner a name, as you say. What I want to say that the full path is not a shape, the shape is only the block. Needless to say that I can be wrong, I am only guessing.

Comment: You are right. In this particular example it would be easier (and cleaner) to draw just one continuous path. However, may circuits possess nodes with multiple branches on them so continuous paths are difficult or even impossible. Also, the line joins appear to be clean...

Comment: If I compile your example and zoom into the bottom right corner then both under Preview (Mac) and Acrobat Reader there is a little corner missing. This does not happen with my above suggestion. But to answer your question, you can also infer the coordinate from the others, e.g. the bottom right corner is `(somebipole-|Rcorrect)`, try e.g. `\draw (somebipole-|Rcorrect)
    -- ++ (1,-1);`, so there is no need to add an auxiliary coordinate, at least in this case.

Comment: I cannot see any line join mismatch, however, when creating nodes with multiple branches, the mismatch would be hidden behind the conjunction marker created with `-*`. I agree that in the particular case of my example, there is no need to use the right terminal coordinate/anchor. However, there are various situations, where I would need it, that's why I asked for it.

Comment: Resistors offer 8 anchors: `north`, `north east`, `east`, `south east`, `south`, `south west`, `west` and `north west` beside `left`, `center` and `right`.  Anchors are tighten to symbol borders. If you like to start branch with resistor after resistor label, you can use in your case `yshift`: `\draw ([yshift=4mm] somebipole.north east) to[R,name=Rwrong,l=Rwrong] ++(0,4);` (if I understood your question correct).

Comment: That workaround does work, because the terminal connectors are approximately(!) 4.3... mm long. However, this is a very quick-and-dirty attempt I was looking for the exact anchor or coordinate.

Comment: It should be noted that many anchors have aliases (in, out, left, right. n, e, s, w, etc.) but with certain exceptions they all share the same 9 locations.

Comment: @JohnKormylo if there are elements without the geographical anchors that's a bug (they're used in a lot of Ti*k*Z, for example using the library `fit`): I tried to add all of them in the past but clearly I can have missed some... ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat you are right

Comment: @Rmano - there are some anchors in odd locations (like center and Center in logic gates).

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes --- I know that --- I used your code to optionally have the center in the right place ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you got something confused... The European resistor component has no leads in its shape, it's just the rectangle.

When you say `\draw (0,0) to[R] (4,0);`, `circuitikz` draws a line from `(0,0)` to the `left` anchor of the element R (on the rectangle), then from the `right` anchor to `(4,0)` and places the node in the middle of the path. In your case, using `R` and `european`, the node name is  `genericshape`. That node has no leads in the shape (some elements have them, but normally  bipoles don't). So there are no other anchors between `(0,0)` and the component (or on the other side) because there is just a line there.

You can see the shape of the bipole using it as a node with its shape name, that you can find in the manual. Try for example `\node[genericshape] at (0,0) {} ;` to see the bare component shape).

[image: genericshape, a bare rectangle]

And you can have even a clearer idea of what's happening if you use a too-short path:

```
 \draw (0,0) to[R] ++(0.5,0);
```

results in

[image: genericshape with wire inside]

Comment: The resistor just being a node in the path explains a lot. So the "leads" are actually arbitrarily long wires and it makes no sense to define the node's anchors on the wires' ends. Thanks!